# <a href # > is not Hitting Controller with # in .Net MVC

Tags: html, jquery, css, .net, asp.net-mvc

Hi I'm trying to use `a href #` tag to navigate different actions in the controller, below is my csHtml code, I can successfully navigate to `Student /add` method with working functionality but the somehow same logic is not working with different URL which is `<a href="#/Department/AddDepartmentNew">`,
both are partial pages.

I have tried the following

1. used `@Url.action`
2. used `@Html.Actionlink`
3. ../department/AddnewDepartment
4. ~/department/AddnewDepartment

above 4 are working fine but CSS not getting applied to the page and getting error $ is not defined jquery error in console.
Please Help me in this, Thank you in advance.

```
<div class="row">
    <a href="#/Student/Add">Add Student</a>
</div>
<br />
<div class="row">
    <a href="#/Department/AddDepartmentNew">Add Department</a>
</div>
```

Comment: The four urls that are working are actual page transfers.  A url that starts with a `#` is not a page transfer.  It is an in page navigation link

Comment: @Taplar Yea, but my CSS, jquery is breaking when transfers, how should I fix it?

Comment: We would need to see your css and jquery logic first to attempt to figure out those issues.